# How to neutralize box-shadow?

Tags: css

Currently I'm using this

```
box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset;
```

but on specific size of screen I don't want box-shadow.

How can i override to disable the shadow?

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Use [CSS3:: Media Queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) to create style based on the screen resolution. And use

```
box-shadow: none;
```

To disable the shadow.

Comment: Oh ok. I know about media query I was just looking for unset box shadow. Thanks. didn't thought it was so easy :)

Comment: How about in the case of an Ipad 2 which has a resolution of 1500x, but I do want mobile laptop user's with a small screen to see it ..